# require_relative Jruby undefined method

Tags: tomcat, jruby, require

I'm trying to use JRuby to launch a Sinatra app in Tomcat. Simple stuff is working, but once I put in something with a require_relative, I get:

undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038

It then says "in 'require'" and references a line in my main ruby file that has neither a require nor require_relative.

At first I was using Jruby 1.4.0, now 1.6.0, the result is the same both times.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_relative` is a Ruby 1.9.2 feature, so are you using the --1.9 switch?

Comment: I have it set as an environment variable. I'm launching via tomcat so I don't know how to confirm that JRuby picking up and obeying the option.

Comment: You can simply output the `RUBY_VERSION` constant ;)